# Redis - Representing hierarchies

Tags: data-structures, redis, hierarchy

I have a lot of data (about 6.5M rows) that I want to supplement with Redis.  Basically, I want to use sorted sets to store the hierarchy of the data.  So, some sample data may look like this (using a family tree as an example).

```
royalty_id | name         | date      | favorite_color | parent
================================================================
       990 | George VI    | 1895-1952 | purple         | NULL
       991 | Margaret     | 1930-2002 | green          | 990
       992 | Elizabeth II | 1926-     | yellow         | 990
       993 | Edward       | 1964-     | purple         | 992
       994 | Andrew       | 1960-     | brown          | 992
       995 | Anne         | 1950-     | pink           | 992
       996 | Charles      | 1948-     | purple         | 992
       997 | Harry        | 1984-     | red            | 996
       998 | William      | 1982-     | blue           | 996
       999 | George       | 2013-     | blue           | 998
```

You get the idea.  The hierarchies that I have aren't very deep (maybe 8 entries deep at most?), there's just a LOT of them.  As I go through the list of entries, I'd like to put them in a redis sorted set like this:

```
lpush ancestors_of.999 998
lpush ancestors_of.999 996
lpush ancestors_of.998 996
```

And so on.  The problem is, that these entries aren't in a nice order in the database like they are in this sample data.  For each row, I could be looking at the bottom, top, or middle of the hierarchy.  So, what's the best way to do this?

Here's some options I've thought about:
1) Continue as the example above, but for each database row, search the existing entries for every list to see if the new row is in there already (seems very inefficient).
2) Maintain another set with parent to which list they're in (seems to be doubling work).

I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Comment: "I have a lot of data (about 6.5M rows)"...no you don't :-)

Comment: What kind of problems are you facing? Too long query times?
If it is too long query times, I Would suggest you to cache them for some time. Either locally or in a simple redis hash. Especielly since the data you shown, seem to be very static(parent's don't change that often)

Comment: @Martinb - It will actually be replaced and rebuilt nightly.  It's not family data, that's just a sample.  We hit this heirarchy often, so instead of having to traverse it in the database, I wanted to somehow design it in Redis to supplement the database info.  I just haven't done a lot of development in Redis, and was needing some help with the design.

Comment: @raffian - If I had a dollar for every row...

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/IsLJ4PlBo9E everything depends on how your data is going to be accessed and how you want to optimize it.

Comment: @akonsu - Lots of good info there, thanks.